# Clear data from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Here is what I am trying to do:

- I have a directive with graphs that ng-repeat data from a service array.
- When I go from one page using the directive to another the directive has information from the first page. So if compliance is at 80% for person1 when I go to see person2 with a compliance of 50% I still see person1's information.

I tried `$state.reload()` which started an infinite loop.

I tried clearing the scope variables on $rootScope.$on($stateChangeLeave) etc.

Here is what my html looks like ( the compliance-gauge is the directive):

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="gauge in regulatorDict[license.reg_id].gauges">
                    <compliance-gauge license="regulatorDict"
                                      id="license.reg_id + gauge.name"
                                      key="gauge.name"
                                      value="license.applied[gauge.value]"
                                      max="gauge.max"></compliance-gauge>
```

Here is the directive js file:

```
export default function() {
  'ngInject';
  'use strict';

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      key: '=',
      id: '=',
      value: '=',
      max: '='
    },
    templateUrl: template,
    controller: function($scope,$state) {
      'ngInject';

      let percentage = ($scope.value / $scope.max) * 100;
      let gaugeColors = ['#72C02C', '#f8ac59', '#ED5565'];
      $scope.colorDict = {};
      $scope.newId = $scope.id.split(' ')[0];
      if (percentage >= 66) {
        $scope.colorDict[$scope.newId] = gaugeColors[0];
      } else if (percentage >= 33 && percentage < 66) {
        $scope.colorDict[$scope.newId] = gaugeColors[1];
      } else {
        $scope.colorDict[$scope.newId] = gaugeColors[2];
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using diferent routes for those person data? Could you share some directive javascript code?

Comment: I just included the directive index.js file above, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: both pages "regulatorDict[license.reg_id].gauges" is the same?

Comment: Yup, but pages are the same